# SQLite WHERE clause being ignored

Tags: sqlite

I've got a really simple query that is returning results that I'm pretty sure shouldn't be included.

```
CREATE TABLE hits
AS SELECT *
FROM deduped_table
WHERE Bank LIKE '%monex%' OR Bank LIKE '%cibanco%' OR Bank LIKE '%intercam%'
AND (Bank_Country = 'US' OR Bank_Country = 'United States');
```

When I look at the hits table, the Bank_Country column has results other than 'US' or 'United States'.  Why?

Answer (score 4):

With parentheses added to show [SQL's precedence rules](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops), your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM deduped_table
WHERE Bank LIKE '%monex%'
   OR Bank LIKE '%cibanco%'
   OR (Bank LIKE '%intercam%' AND
       (Bank_Country = 'US' OR Bank_Country = 'United States'));
```

Answer (score 3):

To complete @CL.'s answer, your query *should* read

```
SELECT *
FROM deduped_table
WHERE (Bank LIKE '%monex%'
   OR Bank LIKE '%cibanco%'
   OR Bank LIKE '%intercam%') AND
       (Bank_Country = 'US' OR Bank_Country = 'United States');
```